# Calculate probability of dying in school shooting using spatial statistics

Tags: probability, spatial, weights, weighted-data, rare-events

Some public commentators say that the chance of dying in a school shooting is very low, so they conclude that Americans over-react to them.

https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/school-shootings-are-extraordinarily-rare-why-is-fear-of-them-driving-policy/2018/03/08/f4ead9f2-2247-11e8-94da-ebf9d112159c_story.html

> The Education Department reports that  roughly 50 million children attend public schools for roughly 180 days per year. Since Columbine, approximately 200 public school students have been shot to death while school was in session......That means the statistical likelihood of any given public school
> student being killed by a gun, in school, on any given day since 1999
> was roughly 1 in 614,000,000. And since the 1990s, shootings at
> schools have been getting less common.

Somehow, **the method behind this calculation doesn't seem right to me**, because **it doesn't take population density and geographical area into account**.

Consider this extreme and hypothetical case: All 50 million of those kids go to one school. Even if only 200 kids die in that time span, that number could have easily been much higher, due to **the proximity of the surviving kids to the bullets.**

On the opposite end of this spectrum, if there are 50 million schools in the US to teach each child individually, then 200 kids dying from school shootings would still be awful and terrible, but it would not be nearly as scary. **Each school shooting could have affected only one child.**

The reality is somewhere in between. According to this website,

[https://admissionsly.com/how-many-schools-are-there/#:~:text=for%20local%20universities.-,How%20Many%20Public%20Schools%20in%20the%20US%3F,30%2C160%20are%20public%20secondary%20schools](https://admissionsly.com/how-many-schools-are-there/#:%7E:text=for%20local%20universities.-,How%20Many%20Public%20Schools%20in%20the%20US%3F,30%2C160%20are%20public%20secondary%20schools).

there are 97,568 public schools in the US.

**I'm looking for a way to calculate the probability of a child dying in a shooting at a public school in the US while incorporating or weighting the relevant spatial statistics.** The following factors come to mind right away:

1. the number of students per school (if a school has more kids, then one shooter has an easier time to kill more kids in one incident)
2. the geographical area of each school (a smaller school is easier for one shooter to travel around and find more kids to kill)
3. how close the schools are to each other (if a high school is close to a feeder elementary school, then the shooter can travel easily between the 2 schools to find more kids to kill). ***Update on 2022-05-31: As Jeremy Miles pointed out below, this factor may not be that important, so please feel free to disregard it to simplify the math.***

Assume that the shooter has infinite bullets. This is not realistic, but a shooter should be considered as dangerous as possible until the police kill or arrest the shooter. Until then, we should assume that the shooter can kill as many kids as possible; this simplifies the math, but also underscores how urgent it is for the police to catch the shooter quickly.

I am not trained in spatial statistics, so I don't know how to do this. Can a specialist in that field help out?

The principles underlying my question are equally applicable to other rare but traumatic events, like terrorist attacks, so this has broad applications.

I recognize that there is likely no one solution to my problem, but any ideas would be great.

Comment: If a school has more kids, each kid is less likely to die, but there are more of them, so it balances out. Shooters (almost) never travel between two schools.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Your first point is astute. Do you have a source for the second point?

Comment: I don't - I just don't recall it happening. I think that in the columbine school shooting (at least in a book I read about it) the shooters tend to stop shooting before they run out of bullets, they don't stop shooting because they run out of people to shoot.

Comment: @JeremyMiles That's OK, and perhaps you're still right. A shooter probably has enough victims at one school to shoot before getting arrested or killed by the cops. For anyone who has ideas to deal with the other factors, I will remove this as a factor to simply the math.

Comment: Do you have any data? What I mean is the dataset where all the features mentioned by you are present? If not, there is no question, because it cannot be calculated without data.

Comment: @Tim No, I can't find any right now, so what I'm looking for is the theoretical methodology. Can we preserve the question to focus on that?

Comment: @Iterator516 As stated like this, you seem to be describing something like logistic regression, you are not describing anything related to spatial statistics.

Comment: Regardless of which extreme scenario you consider, the chances (which likely do vary with location) will remain on the order of less than $10^{-8}$ per child per day. If you want to do a more meaningful analysis, take a look at the 40K+ annual gun-related deaths in the US and study those spatially: they create a risk that is several orders of magnitude greater and for which more data exist. The data are woefully incomplete and expensive to collect, though, because for decades the US gun lobby has successfully prevented scientific study of this risk.

Comment: BTW, collecting the data is a big deal.  I joined a team that spent over a year and hundreds of hours just obtaining and curating reliable data about mass shootings in the US c. 1975-2015 for the civil litigation in the Aurora, CO theater shooting.  Maybe there's a source of such data now, but back then (2015) we found only conflicting, scattered data sources; nothing comprehensive. Perhaps more recently one of the major news outlets (like the NYT, WSJ, or WaPo) has assembled a dataset: that would be the first place to look.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I recognize that. I don't have the vocabulary or the knowledge to describe it using spatial statistics, so I'm hoping that someone who knows this field well can translate what I want from English to spatial statistics. I know that we are supposed to ask perfectly rigorous and well-posed questions on this forum, but please forgive those of us who are trying our best to articulate what we want without the technical fluency to do so.

Comment: We don't ask for technical fluency or "perfect rigor:" we seek only *clarity* and to *resolve ambiguity.* Usually it's best to describe your question in your own terms, defining any specialized ones along the way.  I have some legitimate claim to being an expert in spatial stats, though, and I'm trying to suggest you consider alternative investigations for several reasons. Some of those are related to the rarity of the events; others are related to the difficulty of collecting suitable data; yet others are because the methods are *extremely* complicated. This is not a field for beginners.

Comment: I think all this data is starting from a false premise. Start by looking at the number if children shot, not the number dead. Parents don’t want the children torn apart by bullets or dead. So you brilliant Pew people rework all you numbers on shot or wounded, to make that as clear as I can. I suspect you will say that that is such a small difference it makes no difference unless you now have a child suffering with multiple problems of an impaired body. Sorry I didn’t do what you asked. This is what was on my mind. Pass it on to the Pew people, please.

Comment: Wouldn't you just find out how many students there are enrolled in the year and divide it by the number of students shot in that year?

Comment: That statistic is very miss leading, sure the chance of dying or getting shot on any one day is small.  The expectation is to live through 12+ years of 180 days of school! So 1 in 600 million becomes less than 1 in 300K.  Also if we take into consideration the  surviors of a killed classmate (that could have been me), it becomes far too frequent.  More likely to die in school then from a vaccine.

Comment: @Dave2e 1 in 400k is also small relative to the 1 in 650 per 12 years that don't survive due to other risks. (I am not saying that small risks are not important, but comparing to vaccines which are more likely to cure than to kill and *reduce* the death rates, is exaggerated)